# Strongly typed form in MVC which maps to a different type?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, strong-typing

When I specify form inputs with the @Html.TextBoxFor method, then the generated input element would not necessarily map to the type that is expected in the form's action method.

Let's say I have two classes:

```
public class HomeA
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}

public class HomeB
{
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

HomeA is the model of my view. If a controller action expects HomeB, then I can't provide the necessary input element in a strongly typed manner in my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A)
}
```

This form will obviously not map to HomeB's property.

Comment: If `HomeA` and `HomeB` are identical except for their names, why do you need two classes to begin with? Metadata?

Comment: Cory: HomeA may be used to display various information, while HomeB only contains data which is necessary to save something in a datastore.

Comment: Ok, so like a Model vs. a DTO. Are you aware that you can instruct a controller to ignore certain fields when binding to a model on an action method?

Comment: @Cory: Maybe I misunderstand you, but I can't see how that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The controller action should not expect HomeB.
Use one view model per action.
If you are sending a ViewModel of XYZ, then in general your ActionMethod takes a ViewModel of XYZ.
Thats my general thoughts anyways for consistency/readability.
However if it works for you, do it as long as the relation is there.

[ASP.net MVC - One ViewModel per View or per Action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407596/asp-net-mvc-one-viewmodel-per-view-or-per-action)

As for the note on composition vs. inheritance check out
[ASP.NET MVC Architecture : ViewModel by composition, inheritance or duplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954102/asp-net-mvc-architecture-viewmodel-by-composition-inheritance-or-duplication)

Check out 
http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/04/24/how-we-do-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

You would create a HomeAB class that contains both a HomeA and HomeB

Answer (score 0):

If you have to create and to show some items which belong to both classes A & B, you can design an interface and then inherit that interface. Or you can create another class AB which inherits from A & B.

Hope this helps!