# Should View Models always contain the inputs for forms in that view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, strong-typing

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097866/strongly-typed-form-in-mvc-which-maps-to-a-different-type?rq=1), but I think in my example I have detail which may alter answers.

Say I have a User action on a Controller that renders a View for displaying data about a particular User, it might have a `UserViewModel` like so:

```
public class UserViewModel {
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    etc...
}
```

However, in this View, as well as showing this user data, I want to have a search textbox for the user so they can look up another user on this page. This form would post into an action of FindUser, which accepts the following model:

```
public class FindUserInputViewModel {
   [Required]
   public string SearchQuery;
}
```

If this action finds the model to be invalid, it redirects back to the User action, maintaining the ModelState.

Now, currently to show the validation error, I cannot use a strongly-typed helper as that search query property isn't in `UserViewModel`, I'd have to do this:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchQuery")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor("SearchQuery")
```

This works, and the error will be displayed, as well as the old value that was POSTed being shown (as it is persisted in the ModelState). However, I'd prefer to use a strongly-typed helper wherever possible.

From all the examples I have seen, the pattern here seems to be that the `UserViewModel` should contain the FindUserInputViewModel inside it, perhaps as an `FindUserInput` property. I could then do:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FindUserInput.SearchQuery)
```

This also works, as long as I make sure my FindUser action binds to the correct prefix, or I specify a name in the TextboxFor method call.

However, I don't really see why my UserViewModel should contain this other ViewModel simply for the case of binding the validation using this helper. Does it bring other benefits that I am not seeing? I understand the use of it if your View's model is needing to render out the same data you are posting, such as on a typical Edit action, but that isn't the case here.

It looks like to me that what would be handy here is a another generic helper that can reference a different type, something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxForType<FindUserInput>(m => m.SearchQuery)
```

This doesn't exist, but I think I should be able to write that, and this is a good case for one. Does that sound like an appropriate solution, or am I missing something here?

Another option entirely is perhaps that the small-form for posting in that `FindUserInputViewModel` should have its own GET action as well as POST, and then the User View can just call into it using `@Html.Action`. It could then render a partial-view that is only strongly typed to `FindUserInputViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a partial view for your search and simply pass this a new `FindUserInputViewModel` from your user view?

```
@Html.Partial("FindUser", new FindUserInputViewModel())
```

You can type your partial view to `FindUserInputViewModel` and use strongly-typed helpers in there. I'd say this is the simplest and neatest approach, unless there's something I'm missing?